# Need assistance with simple neo4j rest proof of concept

Tags: java, rest, neo4j

I have two simple classes for testing a rest call on a neo4j server.
I have placed the .jar file in the plugins directory with the path included such as:

```
gov/lanl/graphing/execute/rest/HelloWorldResource.class
```

I have modified the neo4j-server.properties file such as:

```
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_class=
     gov.lanl.graphing.execute.rest=/gov/lanl/graphing/execute/rest
```

I think I have a lack of understanding regarding the above property.

Here are two classes, the HelloWorldResrource class is the one in the plugins direcotry.  Note: there is some cooky cutter syntax so disregard the weird variable names and such.

This is extremely simple, and I think the problem is I don't understand how the path in the server.properties file is supposed to be represented in the Main class.  Thanks for any help.

```
public class Resting {

    public static String URI = "http://localhost:7474/gov/lanl/graphing/execute/rest/helloworld/";
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
        WebResource cypher = client.resource(URI + "rico");
        ClientResponse cypherResponse = cypher.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(ClientResponse.class);
        cypherResponse.close();
        System.out.println(cypherResponse);
    }
}


@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/{name}")
    public Response hello(@PathParam("name") String name)
    {
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(
                ("hello there , " + name).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after much wrangling of my j.v. code, I found a couple errors.

First off:
    org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_class=
should be: 
    org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=

Secondly:

I didn't configure my .jar file correctly, I reconfigured this compilation to include the classpath and the descending directories, correctly.  problem solved. on to more difficult problems....